# document.addEventListener('keydown', console.log("test")); not working as expected

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm starting out with javascript and just want to run a simple test to see if my key presses are being detected.

I'm using the chrome console to test my js output.

```
<script> 
document.addEventListener('keydown', console.log("test"));  
</script>
```

I was expecting in my console to get "test" printed every time I pressed a key while on the webpage. However, all I get is one single "test" when I load the page. Then when I press keys, nothing happens.
What am I not understanding?

Comment: Note how `addEventListener` takes a function as its second argument.

Comment: What @Carcigenicate said. Use `() => console.log("test")` (or `function() { console.log("test"); }` if you can't use arrow functions)

Comment: You need to give it a callback function as the second argument. The way you wrote it, console.log(“test”) will execute immediately and give its result as the callback. You need to instead wrap that in a function and pass the function in as your second argument.

Comment: Makes sense, and got it to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action is expecting a function, so you need to wrap it in one.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function() {console.log("test")});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the log command in a callback function. Otherwise it just executes immediately when the page loads (as you've noticed). If you pass the function to the addEventListener command, it can save it for later and run the function only when the event occurs.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) { console.log("test") });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `document.addEventListener(...)` method takes a function as the second argument.
You could wrap the `console.log` in a function:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function() { console.log("test"); });
```

or declare a separate function and call that:

```
function LogIt(ev) {
  console.log("test");
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', LogIt);
```

You can reference
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

There is a relatively new operator that is being suggested. Arrow Functions.
Similar to a delegate in C#. However, you may want to review browser compatibility if using this in a production environment. If just learning, no worries!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions